# Is there a better way to assign CSS class-names depending on a condition in React?

Tags: reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules

I'm programming an indicator component with React using Babel and ES6 syntax and for styling the component I am using CSS Modules. The component is working fine but I would like to improve the quality of my code.

In each state of the indicator the color of the dot changes.

```
import React from 'react'
import ClassNames from 'classnames'

import styles from './Indicator.css'

const Indicator = (props) => {
  const { current, number, enabled } = props

  if (enabled) {
    const dots = []
    for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
      // FIXME: It must be a better way to implement this
      let dotStyles = ClassNames(styles.dot, {
        [styles.red]: current === i && i === 0,
        [styles.orange]: current === i && i === 1,
        [styles.yellow]: current === i && i === 2,
        [styles.green]: current === i && i === 3,
        [styles.gray]: current !== i
      })
      dots.push(<div className={dotStyles} key={i} />)
    }
    return <div className={styles.indicator}>{dots}</div>
  } else {
    return <div />
  }
}

const { number, bool } = React.PropTypes
Indicator.propTypes = {
  number: number,
  current: number,
  enabled: bool
}

export default Indicator
```

The CSS defining the styles use CSS Modules and the composes keyword

```
.indicator {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  height: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.dot {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.gray { composes: gray from '../../colors.css'; }
.red { composes: red from '../../colors.css'; }
.orange { composes: orange from '../../colors.css'; }
.yellow { composes: yellow from '../../colors.css'; }
.green { composes: green from '../../colors.css'; }
```

I have two questions about this approach:

- It's a little bit cumbersome to reassign all the used colors to a class to then assign it depending in a condition. Is there something am I missing?
- Is there a better way to deal with state and classNames assignation in React? This one is a simple example but I have some really nasty conditionals in other code and I would like to avoid them.

I have been looking into [react-css-modules](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules) but so far I think I don't mind having the styles.class all over the code.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the react-css-modules package to optimize the code.

```
const dots = []
for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
  const dotClassList = ['red-dot', 'orange-dot', 'yellow-dot', 'green-dot']
  const dotClass = (current === i) ? dotClassList[i] : 'gray-dot'
  dots.push(<div styleName={dotClass} key={i} />)
}
return <div styleName='indicator'>{dots}</div>
```

I also used the compose pattern to have only one class avoiding using the ClassName package.

```
.indicator {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  height: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.dot {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.gray-dot {
  composes: gray from '../../colors.css';
  composes: dot;
}

.red-dot {
  composes: red from '../../colors.css';
  composes: dot;
}

.orange-dot {
  composes: orange from '../../colors.css';
  composes: dot;
}

.yellow-dot {
  composes: yellow from '../../colors.css';
  composes: dot;
}

.green-dot {
  composes: green from '../../colors.css';
  composes: dot;
}
```

Other suggestions are welcome!